# Подбор коэффициентов в модельном уравнении

Tags: python, математика, r, статистика, моделирование

Имеется модель:

R<sub>m</sub> = R<sub>0</sub> * e<sup>(Q * T<sub>a</sub>)</sup> * P/(P + K), где

R<sub>m</sub>, T<sub>a</sub> и P - измеренные значения в выборках, 
R<sub>0</sub> задается вручную, 
Q и K необходимо подобрать.

Проблема следующего характера. Я не математик и даже не знаю как называется процесс при котором находят Q и K. Поэтому поиск (ни в гугле, ни в книгах) не дал никаких результатов. Необходимо подобрать коэффициенты Q и K, чтобы правая часть уравнения максимально близко описывала R<sub>m</sub>. Тут наверное нужен метод наименьших квадратов. Идей никаких, кто знает направьте или объясните что делать. Ранее с подобными задачами не сталкивался. В дальнейшем буду реализовывать как скрипт в R или Python.

Answer (score 1):

Задача называется двумерная оптимизация. (Да, она лежит и в основе МНК). Целевую функцию можно взять оттуда-же. Или - сами интерпретируете свое понимание "максимально близко".   Ввиду "нетривиальности" функции ищем оптимум численными методами, например тем самым градиентным спуском, который очень любят в нейронных сетях. Но у вас вполне можно обойтись без сети. Просто берете любой пакет численного анализа, задаете свои данные и если функция не очень экстравагантная - получаете решение.

Пока писал - пришло в голову еще один путь поиска решения. Линеризируете функцию относительно Q взяв логарифм от правой и левой части. Затем делаете замену переменных L=1/К. В итоге можно строить классическую линейную регрессионную модель с двумя зависимыми переменными. Только когда построите - не забудьте сделать обратные преобразования.